# How to show numbers on errorbar plot d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3.js to do a scatter plot with errorbar on it.I am wondering if it is possible to have mouseover event on each end of errorbar for showing the values.
For example, when the mouse hover over on each end of bar on point A, number 3.9 and 4.1 pop up.
Here is my [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i0ewbJZLYn7uezlJMQp3?p=preview)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Plot</title>
    <style> 
     .axis path,
     .axis line{
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        shape-rendering: crishpEdges;
        }    

    path {
       stroke-width: 1.5px;
       stroke: darkgrey;
       stroke-dasharray:"3, 3";
       }
    </style>
  </head>
 <body>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>  
    <script src="errorbar.js"></script>
    <div id="chart">
    </div>

    <script>

     var data = [
       {x: 4, y: "A", s: 0.1
        },
       {x: 4, y: "B", s: 0.2
        },
       {x: 3, y: "C", s: 0.2
        },
       ];

 data.forEach(function(d){
        d.x = +d.x;
        d.y = d.y;
        d.s = +d.s;
        //return console.log(data);
    })
    //creating the plot
    var m = {t:10, r:100, b:40, l:40 },
        w = 960 - m.l - m.r,
        h = 500 - m.t - m.b;

    var x = d3.scale.linear()
        .range([0, w])
        .domain([0,d3.max(data, function(d){return d.x})]);

    var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
        .rangeRoundPoints([h-18,0])
        .domain(data.map(function(d){return d.y;}));   

   var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(x)
        .orient("bottom")
        .ticks(6);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .scale(y)
        .orient("left")
        .ticks(3);

  var eb = errorBar()
          .oldXScale(x)
          .xScale(x)
          .oldYScale(y)
          .yScale(y)
          .yValue(function(d){return d.y})
          .xValue(function(d){return d.x})
          .xError(function(d){return d.s})
          .yError(function(d){return null});

    var svg = d3.select("#chart")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", w + m.l + m.r)
        .attr("height", h + m.t + m.b)

    var plot = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m.l + "," + m.t + ")");  

    var circles = plot.selectAll("g")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("g")

    var plotErrorbar = circles.append("g")
      .attr("class", "errorBar")
      .attr("transform", function(d) {return "translate("+ x(d.x) +","+ y(d.y) +")"})
      .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
      .call(eb);

    var plotCircles = circles.append("circle")
       .attr("class", "circles")
       .attr({
        cx: function(d) { return x(d.x); },
        cy: function(d) { return y(d.y); },
        r: 8
      })

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate("+ m.l +"," + (h + m.t) + ")")
        .call(xAxis);

    svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .attr("transform","translate("+ m.l +","+ m.t +" )")
        .call(yAxis);

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Just add a tooltip to the element.

Comment: like this? http://bl.ocks.org/Caged/6476579

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make tool tip do the following. Add style for tool tip:

**Step 1** add the following style

```
div.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 60px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 2px;
  font: 12px sans-serif;
  background: lightsteelblue;
  border: 0px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Step 2**
Make a div and add it to body set its opacity to 0

```
// Define the div for the tooltip
var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
  .attr("class", "tooltip")
  .style("opacity", 0);
```

**Step 3:**

On mouse hover make its opacity 1 and mouse out make its opacity 0.

```
var circles = plot.selectAll("g")
      .data(data)
      .enter()
      .append("g").on("mouseover", function(d) {//on mouse over make opacity 0.9
        div.transition()
          .duration(200)
          .style("opacity", .9);
        //to div add the text of your choice.
        div.html(d.x + "<br/>" + d.y + "<br/>" + d.s)
          .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
      })
      .on("mouseout", function(d) {
        div.transition()//on mouse out make opacity 0
          .duration(500)
          .style("opacity", 0);
      });
```

Working code [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/VBHLAkLLAw24YZMNHnvy?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Look at [this plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/515Y7ngE5LYhYSmEG1q8?p=preview) for working demo. You can add some css for tooltip div and then append that div on your object using the mouseover event. Hope it helps.

```
var plotErrorbar = circles.append("g")
  .attr("class", "errorBar")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x(d.x) + "," + y(d.y) + ")"
  })
  .style("stroke-dasharray", ("3, 3"))
  .call(eb)
  .on("mouseover", function(d) {
    console.log(d);
    div.transition()
      .duration(200)
      .style("opacity", .9);
    div.html("x = " + d.x + "</br>" + "y= " + d.y)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 28) + "px");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    div.transition()
      .duration(500)
      .style("opacity", 0);
  });
```